# Set animation curve

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm scrolling through a scroll view dynamically, it works using

```
    -(IBAction) animateTestingTwo{

    [UIView  animateWithDuration:4 animations:^{scroller.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 2000);}];

}
```

However the animation curve is not linear, it needs to be so I'm using this:

```
-(IBAction) animateTestingTwo{

    [UIView  animateWithDuration:4 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{scroller.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 2000);}];

}
```

However it isn't working. Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by `it isn't working`? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

If the duration doesn't matter to you, this can be used:

```
[scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(10, 200) animated:YES];
```

Acconding to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922):

> **animated**
>   YES to animate the transition at a constant velocity to the new offset, NO to make the transition immediate.

You can also try to do this inside an animation block to see what happens.